# Using VBA to change source links within sheets instead of workbook

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm currently attempting to write some VBA into a userform that will allow me to change say all the external links in sheet1 to workbookA, then all the external links in sheet2 to workbookB, then all in sheet3 to workbookC etc. etc.

I've used this code to do all the links in the workbook

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()

Dim Source As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
currentsource = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)

    'This is just a record of the changing source files
     Sheets("Notes").Range("C2") = currentsource

    'txtDirectory is the new source location chosen in my userform 
     Sheets("Notes").Range("C3") = txtDirectory

Source = Sheets("Notes").Range("C2")

ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=Source, NewName:=txtDirectory, Type:=xlExcelLinks

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This works perfectly, however I now need to adapt it to change the links depending on the sheet I'm in.

I've done a lot of googling to no avail, I've also spent quite a bit of time with my head in my VBA books.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Workbook.LinkSources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.linksources.aspx) provides an array of links. but your code does not treat it as an array. Have you tried looping through the array?

Comment: I'm not sure this would make any difference, the code above does what I expect it to do, ActiveWorkbook.Changelink is replacing the array with my new source name however I need a way of specifically targeting the links within certain sheets within the workbook rather than the whole workbook as one.

Comment: I admit to not really wanting to experiment, but perhaps [this answer in Mr. Excel forums](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/555468-changing-link-source-via-visual-basic-applications.html#post2743777) will help.

Comment: Haha entertainly I spent an hour or so earlier banging my head off the desk trying to figure that one out - to me it seems as though the "answer" doesn't actually answer the question. Maybe I need to spend some more time playing around with the code, I can sense an evening in front of my laptop ahead.

Comment: Okay, well. The particularly useful part of that answer is the for loop. You really only need to understand that. It loops through the links and then looks in the specific sheet for that link and changes it if it finds it. This is because for whatever reason the VBA doesn't provide a Worksheet.ChangeLink method. By searching the worksheet instead of calling Workbook.ChangeLink you can explicitly choose which links to change. Certainly a pain, but it looks workable.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will print the name of each link in the workbook to the immediate window. From there you should be able to write logic around which links to deal with based on sheet name.

```
Sub link()
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Variant
x = ThisWorkbook.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
For i = 1 To UBound(x)
Debug.Print x(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i use a similar code to do stuff, you will need to adapt this piece of code :

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet
with Thisworkbook
    For Each Sh In .Worksheets
        For q = 1 To Sh.Hyperlinks.Count
            h = Sh.Hyperlinks(q).Address
            If Left(h, Len(.Path)) <> Left(.Path, Len(.Path)) Then
                If InStr(1, h, "\OBJETS\") > 0 Then 'obtenir le nom du fichier sans chemin
                    h = Mid(h, InStrRev(h, "\OBJETS\", Len(h)) + 1, Len(h))
                ElseIf InStr(1, h, "\Règles\") > 0 Then 'obtenir le nom du fichier sans chemin
                    h = Mid(h, InStrRev(h, "\Règles\", Len(h)) + 1, Len(h))
                Else
                    h = Mid(h, InStrRev(h, "\", Len(h)) + 1, Len(h))
                End If
                Sh.Hyperlinks(q).Address = Replace(Replace(.Path, "\OBJETS", ""), "\Règles", "") & "\" & h
            End If
        Next q
    Next Sh
    Set Sh = Nothing
End With
```